# Why does the child of an eval call from bash get orphaned once the parent bash script dies?

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, process

The behavior I describe is currently observed to happen on OS X.

Bash script `parent-script.sh` contains a command `eval $SCRIPT` where `SCRIPT` is a string such as `./another-script.sh`.

If `another-script.sh` is a long-running script, and I send a signal to `parent-script` while it runs, what appears to happen (I check using `pstree`) is that the subshell executing `another-script` is *not* terminated, it becomes a child of `launchd`.

It has STDOUT still bound to the terminal that launched the `parent-script`.

How can I modify this behavior? Also, what really causes this behavior? (so that I can learn about when to expect this behavior)

The Linux tag is in here because I would like to know how Linux behaves here if it does differently.

I am also beginning to realize I am perhaps scratching the surface of a very deep topic. So links to good reading material are welcome!

Comment: A temporary solution to the specific problem I'm dealing with is to change the caller script to not use `eval`. But that does not answer the real question of why child-reaping does not occur.

Comment: Using `eval` or not using `eval` doesn't make a difference here. The same thing would happen without `eval`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is normal and expected.

You sent a signal (presumably **SIGTERM**) to `parent-script` and it died, but no signal was sent to `another-script`. It keeps on running.

This is different than what happens when the `parent-script` job is running interactively on a terminal and you type **^C** (or **^Z**). In that case, a **SIGINT** signal is automatically sent to the whole foreground process group. Since `another-script` is un the same process group as `parent-script` (by default), they both get the signal and they both die.

If you want `another-script` to die automatically when its parent dies in any other context than when it's a job running in a terminal with job control, you have a few options.

- `parent-script` can trap the **SIGTERM** signal. In the signal handler, it kills its child, and then exits itself. This, of course, is not reliable: if `parent-script` crashes or is killed with an untrappable signal, the cleanup won't happen. But it's usually considered good enough.
- Often, `another-script` will naturally exit when its parent exits and you don't have to do anything special. This is often true if the two processes are exchanging data through pipes: the child will get an EOF (if reading) or a **SIGPIPE** or **EPIPE** (if writing) and therefore notice that its parent is gone and exit by itself.
- Otherwise, `another-script` can take explicit steps to check periodically whether its parent is gone, and exit automatically if it finds it it has become a child of `init`/`launchd`. Again, you can use a pipe or other IPC mechanism for this, but the simplest is probably for it to check its own parent process ID.

Comment: Thanks. I think that last bullet point sounds like a serviceable safety net. It is just strange that when I changed this part of my script to call its command through another script (which evals it), all of a sudden it no longer dies with the original caller anymore.

Comment: I actually cannot explain why my original ("intended") behavior happens. My script depends on it, the behavior is consistent, but basically it calls `long-running-filesystem-monitor-script.sh | script-with-while-read-loop-to-produce-actions-on-file-changes.sh >> log_for_this_madness.log &`. It should really just keep going after the parent script quits (which it does by completing execution, not by handling a signal).

Comment: Hey @Celada, congrats on your 10K rep!!! I gave you those last two points (and 8 more on top!)

Comment: @StevenLu: much appreciated. Keep it up yourself, you're almost halfway there! I love it when I post an answer and still manage to learn something I didn't know.

Comment: Hey so to achieve bullet point number 3, is the canonical way to do this just checking if `$PPID` is still alive? I guess there are many checks that would accomplish it: Is original parent PID alive, is current parent `init`/`launchd`, is current parent PID not original parent PID. Looks like all three require calling out to `ps`.

Comment: oh, i think comparing current parent PID to original parent PID should be more bulletproof: What if (on the not completely unlikely chance) that a new unrelated currently running process has gained the same PID as my original parent had?

Comment: I was going to suggest checking if the ppid changed for exactly the reason you said checking if the original ppid is still alive (because it could be replaced), but, disapointingly, the shell doesn't seem to update the `$PPID` variable when the actual parent process ID changes. The variable keeps its old value. I guess this forces you to check the real parent process ID with something like `ppid=$(ps -oppid -p$$ | tail -1)`.

Comment: Brilliant, I had come up with `[[ $(ps -p $$ -o ppid | tail +2) =~ [\ ]1$ ]]`, I suppose it needs a little testing to ensure `ps` doesn't use a tab before the numbers in its output.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to emulate what you observed (on Mac OS X 10.8.4), using the pair of scripts:

#### parent-script.sh

```
SCRIPT=./another-script.sh
trap "echo Exiting; exit 1" 0 1 2 3 13 15
eval $SCRIPT
trap 0
echo "Normal exit"
```

#### another-script.sh

```
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do echo "Sequence $i"; sleep 2; done
```

When I ran it, I got, for example:

```
$  ./parent-script.sh
Sequence 1
Sequence 2
Sequence 3
Sequence 4
^CExiting
Exiting
$
```

When I modified `another-script.sh` like this:

```
trap '' 1 2 3 13 15
for i in $(seq 1 100)
do echo "Sequence $i"; sleep 2; done
```

I got the (aberrant?) behaviour:

```
$ ./parent-script.sh
Sequence 1
Sequence 2
Sequence 3
Sequence 4
^CSequence 5
Sequence 6
^CSequence 7
^CSequence 8
Sequence 9
^CSequence 10
^CSequence 11
^\Sequence 12
Sequence 13
Sequence 14
Sequence 15
Sequence 16
Sequence 17
Sequence 18
Sequence 19
Sequence 20
./parent-script.sh: line 3: 71135 Abort trap: 6           ./another-script.sh
Exiting
Exiting
$
```

I had to create another terminal window and send `kill -6 71135` to stop the parent process, which I think is completely wrong.  I sent interrupts to the parent process; it should exit immediately (via the trap) when I do that.  It should leave the child process running; that has insulated itself from interrupts.  I've been exasperated by this behaviour before.  The `eval` is not required to get the effect; it is sufficient to execute the script without it.

However, `ksh` also behaved the same way.  So, either Apple has been careful to introduce the same bug into both shells or that's the way someone (POSIX?) dictates that shells should behave.

Comment: Your last test, though not completely related to the OP's question, is very interesting. I would not have predicted that behaviour. And it happens in Linux too. From additional testing I have done, it appears that the shell only executes signal handlers (even null/ignore signal handlers) *between* executing two lines of the main script. So it waits for the `eval $SCRIPT` to complete (which only happens when you manually kill it and *then* executes the signal handler. I wonder if this might be because the shell's command execution loop is not reentrant. The `sh` manpage doesn't mention it.

Comment: @Celada: that's an interesting observation (handlers executed between commands).  It certainly explains the observed behaviour.  It might be related to 'what is portably doable in signal handlers'.  My strong recollection is that 25 years ago, I could have interrupted the parent shell and while the child (another) shell would have continued (because it was ignoring interrupts), the parent shell would have exited.  However, it is hard to demonstrate now that my memory of 25 years ago is correct (or incorrect).  And actually, the date is more recent than that, probably this millennium, not last.

Comment: Damn. This is quite an alarming regression if it is one. Bash has been tremendously productive for me so far (considering how far I've gotten with the absurdly high level scripting I'm doing with it as of late), I guess I should start backing off on nesting things in hopes of avoiding these signal handler related pitfalls.

Comment: I dunno whether I can call it a regression; I certainly want to, but...memory can play tricks on me.  Celada's explanation makes some sense (or my extension of Celada's observation does, to me).  I noticed the issue fairly recently, in the last decade or so, but I've not previously characterized it as clearly.  I still have a script or two that doesn't work now on Linux / Mac as it used to on Solaris — and this may be part of the reason why.